# Подсчёт количества товара в заказе используя количество товаров в выборке + количество единиц каждого товара в поле по товару

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

sos, прошу помощи, очередная проблемка вывожу список заказов, по каждому заказу надо вывести количество товаров из таблицы **orderitems**, это сделать получилось, но возникла очередная проблема, 
 
в каждом товаре в таблице **orderitems** есть поле **count** которое хранит сколько единиц именного этого товара заказывается, т.е. предположим в заказе два товара по две единицы каждый, получается 2 + 2 = 4 товара в заказе. 
**вопрос** можно ли подсчёт общего количества товар, сделать непосредственно, в запросе? 
**зы:** понял что реально слабоват в sql, но благодаря вам прям прокачиваюсь)

**SELECT** o.uid, o.id as number_order, ..., **count**(o.id) as items_count 
**FROM** orders **as** o 
**INNER JOIN** user **as** su **ON** su.hub_uid = seller_uid 
**INNER JOIN** user **as** cu **ON** cu.hub_uid = client_uid 
**INNER JOIN** orderstatus **as** st **ON** st.id = status_id 
**INNER JOIN** orderitems **as** oi **ON** oi.order_uid = o.uid 
**GROUP BY** o.id

Comment: `SUM()`? В идеале ещё sqlfiddle какой-нибудь добавлять в такие вопросы. З.Ы. не надо покачиваться, надо пРокачиваться

Comment: ))) исправил опечатку спасибо

Comment: @InDevX да sum получилось я count заменил на sum куда передал count и всё сработала. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вопрос можно ли подсчёт общего количества товар, сделать непосредственно, в запросе?

Берёте и прям в селекте считаете)

```
SELECT
    ...
    sum(oi.count * oi.price) AS order_total
FROM
...
```

Вот ссылка на пример: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

Comment: Да именно  так вчера и сделал, только обрамил умножение в дополнительные скобки, а то ошибку выдавал